# Edit link in directory results not displaying

Tags: wordpress, profile

I am working on a front end directory. I have created the profile and checked the box to "Include profile edit links in search results? " in the profile settings.

When I go to the directory page (as logged in user) and find my contact the "edit" link is not there in the search results. The account I am logged in as in an Admin account so it is my understanding the "edit" link should be there for all contacts.

I feel like I am missing something simple.

We are running Civi 4.6.25 with WordPress 4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

In the shortcode when adding a Proile to WP Page/Post there is an option for Search/Public Directory, the shortcode would be something like this

`[civicrm component="profile" gid="#" mode="search"]`

Replacing the # with the ID of that profile. That provides a page that starts with a search to then view results.

If you include `force=1` in the shortcode it will show all results and the search needs to be extended to use to them filter results.

`[civicrm component="profile" gid="#" mode="search" force="1"]`